# Google Analytics: eCommerce tracking seperated by layout

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Already have GA (Universal Analytics) and eCommerce tracking setup on my website.

Is it possible to set a parameter in the tracking data, and separate reports by this datapoint?

For my website I have multiple views/layouts: desktop and mobile

Also i have various user entry points: desktop browser, mobile browser, in-store ordering station (iPad showing desktop layout), iOS app that shows mobile layout ("iframe" type solution).

I already have this separated in my business logic, calling it "channel" - which can be "default", "insTore" or "iosapp".

Can I somehow set this parameter in GA, so I'm able to se sales per "channel"?

I've read something about dimensions and metrics in the docs, but unsure if that is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

[Custom dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) are part of [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en). If you are using ga.js you will have to switch to analytics.js to use universal analytics.

If switching cost is too high, you might want to look into [Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) in the old product.

-- Updated Answer --
You need to use Custom dimensions in  your case. Try something like:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
   'dimension1':  'channel'
});
```

Note that you will need to also setup what the dimension is called as described in the doc i linked to above.

Comment: Sorry.. Are in fact using Universal. Corrected the OP.

Comment: Added some more code to explain the answer. Please mark this question as solved if it worked for you.